# discord.py self-bot replies only to itself

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    channel = bot.get_channel(931570478915657790)
    if message.content == "hello":
        await channel.send("hi!")
```

I'm new at programming. I want to write a bot for my Discord channel to send users "hi" messages who send "hello". But there is a problem, only I (the self bot) can receive the "hi!" message. When I write "hello" from another account, the bot doesn't answer it. Note: I am using a self-bot, not a normal bot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`discord.py` does not support selfbots very well, instead run these commands:

```
pip uninstall discord.py
pip install discord.py-self
```

`discord.py-self` is a copy of `discord.py` which gives more functionality to selfbots. However, selfbots are technically against the discord terms of service, so use at your own risk. Your code should work the exact same.